# ArcMap 10.3 returns DIST_2D in Skline Graphs as angular distance, not linear distance

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, error-999999

The Skyline processing frequently fails with error 999999 and others (050016, I believe).  When I can produce a Skyline feature and then produce a Skyline graph, the horizontal distance returned (titled DIST_2D in the table) is an angular distance, not a linear distance.  The elevation is therefore calculated as an arctangent of the linear vertical distance over the angular horizontal distance, a truly "interesting" result!

Comment: What is your question? This would be suited to a Tech Support incident, except it's missing most of the necessary details (especially the coordinate system of your data source). GIS SE is a question/answer database, not a vehicle for tech support. Please edit your question to ask a focused, on-topic question.

Answer (score 2):

I just run Skyline and Skyline Graph. Results make perfect sense.
FYI DIST_2D is in meters, moreover elevation of point on the horizon was also computed:

[image: Tools outputs]

Read help again.